# Cooling in fridges and air conditioners

Tags: cooling

I am wondering how do fridges and air conditioners cool things. I know the theoretical stuff like gas laws but our teacher could not explain how actually the cooling is achieved (All I know is a compresser does it. And it is not like a tip closed injection syringe compression.)
I mean if I am given all the instruments, how would I make an air conditioner?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about refrigeration and this is an EE site.

Comment: This is a physics question. You should ask on http://physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ride a bycicle? Did you ever had a flat tire and needed to fill air back in?
While compressing the air, it gets hot, you can easily feel that if you touch it.
The hot air goes through pipes and cools down, keeping the pressure. At the point where the compressed air gets released, it gets really cold.
Thats already everything you need for an air conditioner.

Usually it is improved by using a special gas that turns into liquid at high pressure and can store a lot of energy.

The compressor sits outside and gets hot. The compressed gas is running through long pipes cooling down to outside temperature. After entering the house there is a very narrow part in the pipe where the gas is pressed through and the pressure is very low after this point. It gets cold. It goes through long pipes before it is sucked in again by the compressor.